# Proving commutativity of addition of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was studying the proof of R being a field from **principle of mathematical analysis by Walter Rudin** using cut . And to prove this I had to prove that if $x,y\in R $ then $x+y=y+x$. I couldn't prove it. So I took the help of book.

There they have shown that $x+y $ is the set of $r+s $ where $r\in x, s\in y $. Now by the same definition $y+x $ is the set of all $s+r $. As $s+r=r+s $ for all $s,r \in Q$. Hence $x+y=y+x $.

Here is my problem,we have to prove that R is a field and we don't know if Q is a field or not. So how can we assume $x+y=y+x $. So is there any good way to prove this?? Any help would be appriciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field first. Then, you can assume $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field when you are proving $\mathbb{R}$ is a field. So $r+s = s + r$ for all $r, s$ is given.

Comment: $\mathbb Q $ is a field by definition.  It is the smallest ordered field that results directly from the ordered field axioms.  Rudin is proving that the already known and understood ordered field $\mathbb Q $ which doesn't have the least upper bound property is a subfield of an ordered field that does.

Comment: @fleablood It need not be defined that way; it may be defined as the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$, for instance, in which case the fact that it's a field must be proved. (I don't know how Rudin does it.)

Comment: Rudin just says point blank, Q clearly satisfies the field axioms and is thus a field. Which .... isn't unfair, I guess. Point is Rudin assumes it's already known. If we wish to argue it is behooven to us that we need to define what Q is in the first place. I'm... up to the challenge ... on my good days but... not unless, I really believe I need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reread page 6.

"The field axioms clearly hold in Q, the set of all rational numbers, if addition and multiplication have their customers meaning.  Thus Q is a field."

It's a bit of a hand waving but ...  what *is* Q anyway?  We can't prove *anything* about Q unless we define Q first, and the first thing anyone I've ever met does is simply define Q as a field.

I like to think that the field axioms for ordered fields "force" Q into existance.  (1>0 can be proven so 0 <1 <1+1 <1+1+1 <... so N must exist and as -n must exist Z must exist and so $m*n^{-1} $ must exist fo all integer n != 0, so... Q!)

Rudin takes the view we already know Q exists and we were taught it in elementary school and we already *know* addition is commutative and we just check off that the field axioms are satisfied.

I personally don't really like that approach but... well, it's a trade off, I guess.

Comment: And on page *1* in the very *second* sentence: "We shall not, however, enter into any discussion of the axioms that govern the arithmetic of the integers, but assume familiarity with the rational numbers". *sigh* oh, well.... there are always the Peano postulates... But as long as we nail and define Q *before* we start constructing the reals we are fine. And it doesn't *which* method we use to define or prove so long as we do it *first*.